# How can I prove that $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

How can I prove that $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ is connected? I was trying to prove that it isn't because $\mathbb Q$ is not connected but I can't find two open $A,B$ to prove it.

Comment: Sorry, I´m new in it and my english level isn´t the best. $Q$ are the rational numbers. And they are not connected. But I have to demostrate that $Q$X$Q$ are or not connected. I was trying to prove that it isn´t connected but I couldn´t find any open partition for prove it. That´s why I think it´s connected but I don´t know who can I prove it.

Comment: @Meliodas Use http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html to help yourself with tex commands.

Comment: thank you very much, I will use it.

Comment: This is definitely not the best way to prove that $\Bbb Q^2$ is not connected, but it might be a useful fact to know anyway: $\Bbb Q^2$ and $\Bbb Q$ are homeomorphic, so in particular the former is disconnected since the latter is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that $\mathbb Q$ is not connected. That means that there is a set $A\subset\mathbb Q$ such that $A$ is open and closed in $\mathbb Q$ and that furthermore $A\neq\emptyset,\mathbb Q$. So, consider the set $A\times A$.

Comment: Yes, is very clear if you use this way.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The map $f(x,y)=x$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^2.$ If $\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q $ were connected, then $f(\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q)$ would be connected. But $f(\mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q)=\mathbb Q,$ contradiction.

Comment: If f(x,y) continuos then you go of once connected space to another one?

Comment: If $E$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, then $f(E)$ is connected.

Comment: Perfect,thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your initial intuition was correct - $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is indeed **not connected**.

Think about it intuitively. $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is basically a bunch of points sprinkled in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. The easiest way to show that it's disconnected would be to "cut it in half with a line" - that is, find a line $l$ such that $(1)$ there are rational points (= elements of $\mathbb{Q}^2$) on both sides of $l$ and $(2)$ there are no rational points actually *on* $l$ itself.

- Do you see why this would in fact disconnect $\mathbb{Q}^2$?

Now $(1)$ is basically trivial - $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is scattered throughout $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that there are rational points on both sides of *any* line. So we're just down to $(2)$: can you think of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ not containing any rational points? *HINT: there's even a **horizontal** (or vertical, if you prefer) example - think about $\pi$ ...)*

Comment: I understand. I was thinking only in the horizontal of x=0 but if I find one with only irrationals points I have the solution. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Meliodas Yes, and it's not hard to find such a line - do you see how?

Comment: I thought in x=irrational number. In this way (x,y) don´t belong to rational numbers for all the y of the vertical, Is this enough?